# Physical button to run scripts on a Windows machine

Tags: gui, script

I frequently come in contact with people who absolutely cannot operate a PC, no matter how much training they get.

I need some sort of programmable physical button or remote control that executes a script on a Windows machine when it is pressed. (And no, wiseguys, a mouse won't do.)

Does such a thing exist? If so, how can I set it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [USB Panic Button](http://awaregeek.com/funny-stuff/usb-panic-button/) is [scriptable](http://www.johnbruin.net/index.php/2008/11/30/new-software-for-your-usb-panic-button/). Of course it looks pretty silly.

Comment: This needs a siren and big red flashing lights when pressed.

Answer (score 3):

You could map a physical button to some script using [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). For instance I use to map my CAPS-LOCK key to SHIFT :) It is very powerful with its own macro language and loads of tutorials out on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe combine [Vdex's idea](https://superuser.com/questions/17711/physical-button-to-run-scripts-on-a-windows-machine/17734#17734) with a cheapo [USB Presenter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KCT8F6) gadget to get a more "phyiscal" button.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of out-of-the-box, but you can buy buttons designed for arcade machines.  Such buttons will require soldering and programming, or you can wire them into a keyboard.

Barring that, look for emergency switches (think "the big red button" buttons) which can be built into a system and are very easy to operate once installed.

Answer (score 1):

My [Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 4000](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/reviews/12585.aspx) has 5 programmable buttons across the top labeled by number. I put little sticky labels above them to remember which one did what.

You can assign each of these buttons to open an executable. So you could write a script in your favorite language and have the buttons invoke it (call the interpreter to execute a script, maybe).

[image: Microsoft Wireless Comfort Keyboard 4000]

---

*Note:* I don't believe Microsoft sells this particular keyboard anymore but I'm sure there are others like it.

Comment: I bought mine a month ago :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somthing like this could be useful:

[image: usb button set]

http://www.response-box.com/k4227.shtml